# Как сделать так, чтобы правая колонка всплывала вверх?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap

Верстаю сайт на бутстрапе. Нужно сделать так, чтобы та информация, которая отображается на больших экранах в правой колонке, на мобильных устройствах отображалась сверху контентной части. Однако по умолчанию правая колонка уходит вниз.
Как мне сверстать страницу так, чтобы правая колонка уходила вверх?

Код HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>Информация</h2>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed massa sollicitudin, accumsan
                        diam et, luctus elit. Praesent odio est, faucibus a est at, dictum facilisis mi. Vestibulum a
                        libero odio. Sed nec ullamcorper nulla, ac lobortis odio. Donec egestas vel risus ac gravida.
                        Curabitur consectetur lobortis auctor. Fusce cursus semper lorem, ac auctor nunc fermentum sit
                        amet. Pellentesque nec lacus in magna consectetur viverra. Proin quis turpis laoreet, aliquam
                        est ac, lacinia nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur placerat consectetur maximus.
                        Mauris accumsan leo non lacus vehicula efficitur.
                    </div>
                    <div class="galerry">
                        <h2>Фотогалерея</h2>
                        Место для фотогалереи
                    </div>
                    <div class="news">
                        <h2>Новости</h2>
                        Место для новостей
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="search">
                    <h4>Поиск</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="newspaper">
                    <h3>Газета</h3>
                    <div class="last">Содержимое блока</div>
                </div>
                <div class="contacts">
                    <h3>Контакты</h3>
                    <div class="contact">
                        <h5 class="small">jjj</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: А можете конкретизировать рисунком или запускаемым примером кода?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Добавил.

Comment: Да можно было бы ссылку на css сделать, смотрелось бы лучше (Bootstrap CDN). Сделайте, пожалуйста. Правая колонка, это `col-sm-3`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Бутстрап умеет менять колонки местами: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Их надо расположить так, как они будут стоять на мобильном, и при переходе к широкому экрану верхнюю колонку оттолкнуть вправо, а нижнюю вытянуть влево.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
                <div class="search">
                    <h4>Поиск</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="newspaper">
                    <h3>Газета</h3>
                    <div class="last">Содержимое блока</div>
                </div>
                <div class="contacts">
                    <h3>Контакты</h3>
                    <div class="contact">
                        <h5 class="small">jjj</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>Информация</h2>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed massa sollicitudin, accumsan
                        diam et, luctus elit. Praesent odio est, faucibus a est at, dictum facilisis mi. Vestibulum a
                        libero odio. Sed nec ullamcorper nulla, ac lobortis odio. Donec egestas vel risus ac gravida.
                        Curabitur consectetur lobortis auctor. Fusce cursus semper lorem, ac auctor nunc fermentum sit
                        amet. Pellentesque nec lacus in magna consectetur viverra. Proin quis turpis laoreet, aliquam
                        est ac, lacinia nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur placerat consectetur maximus.
                        Mauris accumsan leo non lacus vehicula efficitur.
                    </div>
                    <div class="galerry">
                        <h2>Фотогалерея</h2>
                        Место для фотогалереи
                    </div>
                    <div class="news">
                        <h2>Новости</h2>
                        Место для новостей
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```